# ios - syntax errors on cellForRowAtIndexPath for UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6

I have this declaration for cellForRowAtIndexPath but I get a syntax error:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

and this is the error:

```
"use of undeclared identifier tableView"
```

But in my other controllers where I have the same sort of a setup, I don't get that error. 
Would anyone know why this error happens and how to fix it?

This is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Show the actual line that causes the error, please

Comment: @matt it is this line: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: No it isn't. :) Paste your actual code into the q.

Comment: @matt just pasted the screen shot - see, it is that line :)

Comment: The problem is caused by something wrong with the syntax above the part of the screen shot that you show.

Comment: Probably your curly braces do not match up properly.

Comment: In fact look at the indentation. You probably need one more left curly brace.

Comment: I have it. Cut the entire method and paste it *after* the left curly brace just before `@end`.

Comment: @matt you are right. I feel like an idiot :)

Comment: No, it isn't your fault that the compiler's way of expressing the problem is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have tried to declare a method inside a method. The compiler has reported this in a confused way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the curly braces don't match up. There appears to be an extra one just before **`@end`** at the end of the file.

Comment: Hey, don't steal my answer.

Comment: @matt Sorry. I don't think I stole your answer. I think we answered at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have declared the method inside an method it should be outside any method. So place that function before @end.

Answer (score 0):

you are declared that method inside another method.
and check your curly braces is correct or wrong.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Declare method separately not written in any another method.